# When using npm scripts, how can I tell if I am currently running windwos or mac

Tags: node.js, git, npm, githooks, husky

Since it is a multi-person development, in mac environment, it is required to set chmod + x.usky /pre-commit for projects, but many people may deliberately leave it unset in an attempt to submit the wrong code to the repository

I know you can do this, but this command does not exist on windows. How can I do this command only on mac

```
scripts:{
  "prepare": "husky install && chmod +x .husky/*"`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this command only on mac

You can use this package: [run-script-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os).

Install:

```
npm install --save-dev run-script-os
```

Then set `run-script-os` as the value of the npm script field that you want different functionality per OS.

Then create OS specific scripts.

```
scripts:{
  "prepare": "run-script-os",
  "prepare:macos": "husky install && chmod +x .husky/*"
}
```

The command will then only work when run on MacOS. In other cases it'll say: run-script-os was unable to execute the script 'prepare'.

Comment: On windows, chmod command error is displayed

Comment: Oh, I get the idea. Is there any other solution besides the need for new packages?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.